# mysql subquery error can not be identified. error code 1064

Tags: mysql

what is the error in below mysql query?

```
SELECT distinct d.temp,d.pre FROM Data as d
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT distinct d1.temp,d1.pre FROM Data as d1 where
d1.temp <=d.temp AND d1.pre <>d.pre
AND (d1.temp < d.temp or d1.pre<d.pre) 
)
```

Comment: the table 'data' has only two columns as temp, pre. I amtrying to execute a 2D skyline query.

Comment: comment the error message here

Comment: This might not change your error, but I don't think you need `select distinct` in the `not exists` subquery; just plain `select` should do fine.

Comment: Also, the table name 'data' may be a reserved word. So i changed its name as stats. Still i am getting the same error

Comment: Even though 'disctinct' is removed and plain select is used, still error comes

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://rextester.com/GNH56242) this problem.  Please setup a Rextester or Fiddle.  If you can't, then it means you have no idea what is going on with your query.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Here is fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f1172/3    I am trying to produce skyline of table stats which is all those records with min(t), min(p).

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't load.  Use Rextester instead: http://rextester.com/GNH56242

Comment: Fiddle loads for me.

Comment: And works fine! Didn't you check it?

Answer (score 0):

As per your SQL Fiddle your query executes fine.